# Retornar xml para visualização browser asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso disponibilizar um arquivo XML para ser **visualizado** no **browser**, sem que o usuário precise baixar o arquivo, eu faço isso salvando o arquivo num diretório e depois eu mando o diretório deste arquivo e o browser abre como o exemplo abaixo:

```
public string getXml(int entradaId)
{
    try
    {
        var entrada = ctx.Entradas.Find(entradaId);
        string xml = entrada.Xml;

        var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads");
        string caminhoArquivo = Path.Combine(@uploadPath, entrada.ChaveNota + "-nfe.xml");

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(caminhoArquivo);
        sw.Write(xml);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

        return "/Content/Uploads/" + entrada.ChaveNota + "-nfe.xml";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "Xml Sem Entrada";
        throw;
    }
}
```

Isso funciona, Porém acredito não ser o certo. Pois eu acabo não apagando o arquivo e isso vai lotar a pasta com um tempo.

Eu preciso de alguma forma de retornar este XML para o Browser abrir como um arquivo e disponibilizar a visualização [como exemplo](http://4waysystems.com.br:8081/Content/Uploads/35170221366504000108550010000000431475471050-nfe.xml).

Porém sem que eu tenha que salvar o arquivo físico.

Comment: `entrada.Xml` é uma string?

Comment: @jbueno sim, Seria um XML salvo no SqlServer que me volta como uma string.

Comment: Pronto então =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente salvar o XML só pra mostrar no browser não é boa ideia.

É possível simplesmente retornar `Content` passando como primeiro parâmetro a `string` XML.

```
public ActionResult GetXml(int entradaId)
{
    var entrada = ctx.Entradas.Find(entradaId);    
    return Content(entrada.Xml, "text/xml");
}
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, No meu caso eu chamava via ajax para abrir em nova aba, Mas adaptei o método e me atendeu perfeitamente. Obrigado

Comment: Esta abordagem não é boa. Não há conferência da sintaxe e/ou do formato. O XML pode ser malformado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez a estrutura do XML é conferida em outra etapa do processo, Antes mesmo de ser salvo no BD ele é validado então no retorno ele volta sempre corretamente

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar um Custom [ActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) para isso.

Um exemplo seria:

Chamaremos o nosso Custom `ActionResult` de `XmlActionResult`.

```
public sealed class XmlActionResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly XDocument _document;

    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public XmlActionResult(XDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");

        _document = document;

        // Default values
        MimeType = "text/xml";
        Formatting = Formatting.None;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = MimeType;

        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting })
            _document.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

E em seu `controller`, basta fazer desta forma:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var xml = new XDocument(
            new XElement("root",
                new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
                new XElement("child", "Hello World!")));

    return new XmlActionResult(xml);
}
```

Caso o seu `XML` seja uma string, basta converter antes do retorno, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    String xml ="<Root>Root</Root>";

    return new XmlActionResult(XDocument.Parse(xml));
}
```

Lembrando que você também pode alterar o `XmlActionResult` para fazer o parse, caso deseje.

Caso queira ver outras formas, veja essas perguntas:

- [Return XML from a controller's action in as an ActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134905/4843158)
- [What is your prefered way to return XML from an ActionMethod in Asp.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592885/4843158)

Comment: Eu achei dahora a resposta. Mas acho que ia ser problemático pra ele ter que criar um XDocument já que a `string` já existe. De qualquer forma, fica meu +1 porque isso é bem útil.

Comment: @jbueno Bem lembrado, não havia me atentado a este detalhe. Editado a resposta.

Comment: @jbueno Dá pra fazer em uma linha. Não precisa ser com `XDocument`.